# Proof of inequality of area for quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, inequality, quadrilateral, geometric-inequalities

If $a,b,c,d$ are sides of a quadrilateral, and $S$ is its area, then prove that $$\dfrac{(a+c)^2+bd}{4} \geq S$$.

Comment: What does surface refer to ?..Area , Perimeter??

Comment: @user35508 area, I corrected it